# Why do I get a NullReferenceException when using shelljs to clone a git repo?

Tags: node.js, shelljs

I am attempting to write a fairly simple nodejs program that needs to clone a git repo.

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec('git clone http://mybitbuck.et/scm/myproject/myrepo.git');
```

Throws an error as follows, and then seems to hang without exiting forever:

```
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

There is no additional output or stack trace, not even a line number.  What is going on, and how can I get it working, or at least get more information about what is happening and why?

*I know I could use nodegit or similar instead of using the shell but I think I would benefit from understanding what is happening here HOW to address situations where output is so sparse.*

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in my machine. Actually got

`Cloning into 'myrepo'...`

`fatal: unable to access 'http://mybitbuck.et/scm/myproject/myrepo.git/': Could not resolve host: mybitbuck.et`

Comment: I didn't put my actual bitbucket hostname in the code sample, for probably-obvious reasons. :)

Comment: I think the comment of @Meg is one of the bests I've seen here ^^

Comment: I was just pointing out I didn't get the error, thought it may have happened before the obvious not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this.  It is related to the version of git for windows (2.19.1) that I was running, and updating to the newest version removed the error.

I eventually found the right search term combination that lead me to this bug: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1868